# Magento base font size

Tags: html, css, magento, fonts

OK, so I have developed an html page to put it into a magento site.

It all looks fine except all my fonts are too small when I put it into magento.

I've worked out the reason why.

Basically, I sized everything using ems at the standard 16px size. The magento site has this line :

```
font: 12px/1.55 Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
```

Since all of my code is with in a  div classed .maincontent (with many different divs and font sizes etc within that) is there a way of increasing the base font size from 12px back to 16px for everything within my main div? Or do I have to individually fix every font-size tag in my page?

I hope all of this makes sense!

Comment: Can you provide more details on how are you adding a page to your magento site and a link to the page.

Comment: Hi @Adi sorry, was being stupid - see my answer below!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry - nevermind! had a typo in my code - when I fixed it the usual `font-size:16px;` fixed the issue!